# C++: How should I rearrange this code so the loop checks for both cases?

Tags: c++

I am making a Slot Machine program in C++ as a class assignment. The program is supposed to take a percentage of your total credit (starting at 1000.00) and generate three random numbers to signify the three slot numbers. The user wins if all three numbers match. The game will keep going just so long as the user still has credit, and the program should always ask the user if they want to continue.

I have gotten basically everything I need for the program to work, but my issue is that whenever I play the game and I get a match, it does not prompt the user to enter more credit. Instead it just ends the program. I figured it has something to do with the way I wrote my while loop because the condition only applies for if the numbers don't match, and since they don't match it isn't able to check the first if statement within the loop. I tried using a do-while, but it's the same situation. How can I rearrange the code so it will prompt the user to bet again even if they won?

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

/* Start: Do Not Change */
const int MAX = 5; 
const int MIN = 1;

// This function takes tree ints as parameters
// and sets them to a random number
int spin(int & n1, int & n2, int & n3)
{
    n1 = rand()%(MAX-MIN)+MIN;
    n2 = rand()%(MAX-MIN)+MIN;
    n3 = rand()%(MAX-MIN)+MIN;
}
/* End: Do Not Change */

int main()
{
    int slot1, slot2, slot3;
    double percent;
    double credits = 1000.00;
    char keepPlaying; 

    srand (time(NULL));

    cout << "Welcome to the slots, you have 1,000.00 credits.\n"
    << "What percentage of credits do you want to bet(0-1)? ";

    cin >> percent; 
    spin(slot1, slot2, slot3); // At this point slot1-3 all have a random value between 1 and 5
                                //spin function 
    cout << "Slot value = " << slot1 << "-" << slot2 << "-" << slot3 << endl;

    while (slot1 != slot2 || slot1 != slot3 || slot2 != slot3)
    {
        if (slot1 == slot2 && slot1 == slot3 && slot2 == slot3)
        {
            cout << "\tYou won " << fixed << setprecision(2) << credits *   percent << " credits!\n";
            credits += (credits * percent); 

            cout << "Continue (y/n)? "; 
            cin >> keepPlaying;

            if (keepPlaying == 'y')
            {
               cout << "You have " << credits << " credits left.\n"; 
               cout << "What percentage of credits do you want to bet(0-1)? ";

                cin >> percent; 

                spin(slot1, slot2, slot3);
                cout << "Slot value = " << slot1 << "-" << slot2 << "-" << slot3 << endl; 

                continue; 
            }

            else if (keepPlaying == 'n')
            {
                cout << "You are leaving with " << credits << " credits." <<  endl; 
                return 0; 
            }
        }

        else
        {
            cout << "\tSorry, you lost " << fixed << setprecision(2) <<  credits * percent << " credits." << endl; 
            credits -= (credits * percent); 

            cout << "Continue (y/n)? "; 
            cin >> keepPlaying;

            if (keepPlaying == 'y' && credits != 0)
            {
                cout << "You have " << credits << " credits left.\n"; 
                cout << "What percentage of credits do you want to bet(0-1)? ";

                cin >> percent; 

                spin(slot1, slot2, slot3);
                cout << "Slot value = " << slot1 << "-" << slot2 << "-" << slot3 << endl;

                continue; 
            }

            else if (keepPlaying == 'y' && credits == 0)
            {
                cout << "Get out of here bum!" << endl; 
                return 0; 
            }

            else if (keepPlaying == 'n')
            {
                cout << "You are leaving with " << fixed << setprecision(2) << credits << " credits." << endl; 
                return 0; 
            }
        }
    }

    return 0; 
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

/* Start: Do Not Change */
const int MAX = 5; 
const int MIN = 1;

// This function takes tree ints as parameters
// and sets them to a random number
void spin(int & n1, int & n2, int & n3)
{
    n1 = rand()%(MAX-MIN)+MIN;
    n2 = rand()%(MAX-MIN)+MIN;
    n3 = rand()%(MAX-MIN)+MIN;
}
/* End: Do Not Change */

// How many credits the user has to play with
double credits = 1000.00; // 1000 is the starting point

void doGame(){
    int slot1, slot2, slot3;
    double percent;
    double dCreditsWagered;
    cout << "What percentage of credits do you want to bet(0-1)? ";

    cin >> percent;
    dCreditsWagered = credits*percent;

    spin(slot1, slot2, slot3); // At this point slot1-3 all have a random value between 1 and 5
                                //spin function
    cout << "Slot value = " << slot1 << "-" << slot2 << "-" << slot3 << endl;
    // Check if all slots are equal:
    if( (slot1 == slot2) && (slot1 == slot3)){
        // User won!
        cout << "\tYou won " << fixed << setprecision(2) <<  dCreditsWagered << " credits!" << endl;
        credits += dCreditsWagered; 
    } else {
        // User lost :(
        cout << "\tSorry, you lost " << fixed << setprecision(2) <<  dCreditsWagered << " credits." << endl; 
        credits -= dCreditsWagered; 
    }
}

int main(){
    char keepPlaying;

    srand (time(NULL));

    cout << "Welcome to the slots, you have 1,000.00 credits." << endl;

     do{
        doGame();
        cout << "Continue (y/n)? "; 
        cin >> keepPlaying;
        if (keepPlaying == 'y' && credits > 0) {
            // User would like to play another round
            cout << "You have " << credits << " credits left." << endl; 

        } else if(keepPlaying=='y' && credits <= 0){ // credits should never be < 0, but hey, doesn't hurt to check, right?
            // User does not have enough credits to continue playing:
            cout << "Get out of here you bum!" << endl;
            break;
        }else if (keepPlaying == 'n') {
             // User would like to quit
             cout << "You are leaving with " << credits << " credits." <<  endl; 
             break;
        }

     }while(true);

     return 0; 
}
```

I moved your actual game logic to a function called `doGame()`. When ran, the game enters an infinite do-while loop which executes `doGame()` and then checks if the user wants to continue playing. If the user wants to continue playing and they still have credits left, the loop will restart (and thus `doGame()` will be called again.) If the user chooses to quit or if the user is out of credits and they try to play again, the code will break out of the do-while loop.

I have not tested this code yet, so if you find an error, please let me know so I can fix it.

**Edit**: Just compiled and tested. I found two errors. #1, your `int spin(int &n1, int &n2, int &n3)` function is declared to return an int, but it does not return anything. #2, I was missing a semicolon after `}while(true)` (syntax error).

Aside from those two errors, the code seems to perform as expected. Ideally, one should add a function called `bool keepPlaying()` which would prompt the user to continue playing and then validate that the user's input was either `y` or `n` (and prompt them again if it they entered anything else), but I will leave that up to you :P

Comment: Thank you it's working fine now! I didn't create a function, but I did use the the infinite loop which allowed it to work. Also, I don't know if you could help me, but do you have any knowledge in printing matrices while taking input using the command line? I'm using int argc and char* argv[] for the first time and my professor wanted us to play around with it. I'm trying something that takes the input of rows, columns, and symbols and prints out a matrix using the inputted symbol. (e.g. a 6x6 matrix of X's). I figured atoi and for loops would work but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: @Albert, sure, give me a few minutes and I'll write up an example of that.

Comment: @Albert, here's a link to my example of creating a matrix filled with `'X'`s using arguments: http://pastebin.com/Vgd7mRkA If you need any more help, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: One more question! The line where you assign the matrix[rows][columns] to 'X', how can I change that so it would use any symbol inputted on the command line? I tried setting it to argv[3] but it was an invalid conversion.

Comment: Wait never mind I figured it out lol. Thank you again for all the help!

Comment: @Albert, good question. Remember that `argv` is technically a pointer to an array of characters. Thus, `argv[3]` is a character array even if it is just 1 single character. So you need to pull the character at the first index of the array (which is the only character in the array). `argv[3][0]` should get that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the while loop code below, you may want to give user a choice to end the game. User can end the game if they input `Ctrl+Z`
(Linux) or `Ctrl+d` (Windows):

```
cout << "Welcome to the slots, you have 1,000.00 credits.\n"
<< "What percentage of credits do you want to bet(0-1)? Use EOF to end the game";
while(std::cin >> percent) {
  spin(slot1, slot2, slot3); // At this point slot1-3 all have a random value between 1 and 5
                            //spin function 
  cout << "Slot value = " << slot1 << "-" << slot2 << "-" << slot3 << endl;
  if (allSlotMatchs) {

  }
  else {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally when you want an infinite loop, you use `while (true)` and then `break` on the condition that breaks the loop.

For example,

```
while (true) {

  ...

  if (credits < .01) {

    cout << "Get out of here bum!" << endl;
    break;
  }

  ...

  if (keepPlaying == 'n')
    break;

  }
```

Note, I compared the credit value against a larger value than zero.  The way [floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) values work, you normally can't compare for equality.  This is because they have limited precision (float, double, etc...) and they use a base other than base10 (base2).

You generally can't compute exact values like zero by adding, subtracting, multiplying or dividing.  A number of values can't be represented exactly using base2 floating point as well (actually this includes .01).